# How to select partition for a table created in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I created a table using the "auto detect" in the UI.
By doing that it created the table from Json file.
[image]

Now I want the table to be partitioned by  one of the `TIMESTAMP` columns.

How can I do that? The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect) does not specify how to do it for an existed table.
Can it be done from the UI? If not how can it be done with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the partitioning as part of table creation; you cannot change it after the fact. What you can do is to create a new table with the schema and partitioning that you want, then reload the data. See the documentation for [`CREATE TABLE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#create_table_statement) for the syntax to create a partitioned table. If you want to create the table without having to write out the column list, you can use a query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.newtable
PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp_column) AS
SELECT *
FROM dataset.existingtable
LIMIT 0
```

Note that if you remove the LIMIT 0, you can just create the table and copy the data at the same time, but you will incur a cost. Using LIMIT 0 and then reloading the data will be free.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why it can't be done when auto detecting the table from the Json? Why must I Create table A from auto detect, create table B from table A with paratition, delete table A  ?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the columns aren't known in advance.