# Are LIMIT 0 queries billed in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I was thinking to use this together with DBT to check that all the DAG, dependencies and such is correct without incurring in costs.

I was thinking of adding a `LIMIT 0` in BigQuery queries. I'm not finding any official doc stating whether this is the case.

Are those queries not billed?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51179544/5221944 from ex-BigQuery engineer. and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055280/5221944 by me :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, this will not bill any data.  You can run a dry run to verify:

```
dzagales@cloudshell:~ (elzagales)$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --dry_run 'SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests` LIMIT 0'
Query successfully validated. Assuming the tables are not modified, running this query will process 0 bytes of data.
dzagales@cloudshell:~ (elzagales)$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --dry_run 'SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests` LIMIT 1'
Query successfully validated. Assuming the tables are not modified, running this query will process 254787 bytes of data.
```

Above you can see a `LIMIT 0` bills 0 bytes, while a `LIMIT 1` will scan the whole table.

Comment: As a note check this article out on how auto trader achieves what you’re talking about https://engineering.autotrader.co.uk/2022/04/06/dry-running-our-data-warehouse-using-bigquery-and-dbt.html